# Golang- Getting struct attribute name

Tags: reflection, struct, go

I want to return the name of a struct attribute using the reflect package. So far I have:

```
type MultiQuestions struct {
    QuestionId      int64  
    QuestionType    string 
    QuestionText    string 
}
func (q *MultiQuestions) StructAttrName() string {
    return reflect.ValueOf(q).Elem().Field(0).Name
}
```

However, this gives me a error `reflect.ValueOf(q).Elem().Field(0).Name undefined (type reflect.Value has no field or method Name)`

I tried casting to StructField but that didn't work either. How do I get at the name of Struct?

In this case, the names I am interested in are QuestionId, QuestionType and QuestionText.

Answer (score 6):

You need to operate on the `Type` not the `Value`

```
func (q *MultiQuestions) StructAttrName() string {
    return reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(q)).Type().Field(0).Name
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/UQedovQ3bL)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Type:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type MultiQuestions struct {
    QuestionId   int64
    QuestionType string
    QuestionText string
}

func (q *MultiQuestions) StructAttrName() string {
    return reflect.TypeOf(q).Elem().Field(0).Name
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println((&MultiQuestions{}).StructAttrName())
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/su7VIKXBE2

Answer (score 0):

You also can consider to utility functions defined in [`github.com/fatih/structure`](https://github.com/fatih/structure), like the [`Fields(s interface{}) []string`](https://github.com/fatih/structure/blob/69a6a30d8e7fca1a64ac04d1a2db629079603db0/structure.go#L120-L146) one, which work on pointers or objects, including `struct` fields within the `struct`.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"

    "github.com/fatih/structure"
)

type MultiQuestions struct {
    QuestionId   int64
    QuestionType string
    QuestionText string
    SubMQ        SubMultiQuestions
}

type SubMultiQuestions struct{}

func (q *MultiQuestions) StructAttrName() string {
    return reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(q)).Type().Field(0).Name
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println((&MultiQuestions{}).StructAttrName())
    fmt.Println(Fields(&MultiQuestions{}))
    fmt.Println(Fields(MultiQuestions{}))
}
```

Output:

```
SubMQ
[QuestionId QuestionType QuestionText SubMQ]
[QuestionId QuestionType QuestionText SubMQ]
```

See a full example in this <kbd>[play.golang.org](http://play.golang.org/p/smKfn0lx1t)</kbd>